# Using sql, how do get rows with count for duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I count duplicates rows (where the date and names are the same) using a select statement?

Here is my table

```
id  date        name
1   01/02/12    sam  
2   01/02/12    john  
3   02/04/12    eddie  
4   01/06/12    joe 
5   01/02/12    john  
6   01/02/12    john
7   02/04/12    eddie
8   01/05/12    eddie
9   01/07/12    joe
```

Result should be like this:

```
id  date        name   count
1   01/02/12    sam    1
    01/02/12    john   3
    02/04/12    eddie  2
4   01/06/12    joe    1
8   01/05/12    eddie  1
9   01/07/12    joe    1
```

I need a third coloumn in result set which value will be count column. also i dont need the id if the count is more than 1 (i think that would be impossible anyways). I am using mysql.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138518/count-in-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, date, name, COUNT(1) AS `count`
  FROM table_name
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY date, name
;
```

That will always give the least `id` of the group. If you specifically *want* the first field to be `NULL` when there are duplicates, then you can change `MIN(id)` to `CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1 THEN NULL ELSE MIN(id) END`, but it sounds like you don't care about that?

Comment: I like this method, seems to be the clearest answer, and doesn't require a subquery.

Comment: And you can also get all the ids (when duplicates) adding this in the Select list: `GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS allId`

Comment: Also, you don't actually need `MIN(id)`. MySQL will let you just use `id` to get the ID of one of the rows in the group (it doesn't guarantee which one). Some other RDBMSes are more pedantic about that, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I'm well aware of that feature, but I make a point of neither using nor recommending it. I'm pretty sure its main purpose is to confuse and mislead. (Exception: if I'm `JOIN`ing, and `GROUP`ing `BY` one table's primary key, then I sometimes take advantage of that feature for the other columns. But that's it.)

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
select  id, date, name, count(*)
from mytable
group by id, date, name
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `id` seems to be the primary key; if you `GROUP BY` it, then `COUNT(*)` will always be `1`. (And even once you fix that -- the OP's sample results *do* include non-duplicate rows, so the `HAVING` clause is wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select date, name, count(id) as counter
from mytable
group by date, name
having count(id) > 1
```